# MySQL - Difficult Group By sitation for Battery Maintenance

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing the following fields.

```
EntryID, Date, BatteryID, Capacity, Type
```

**EntryID** is the auto increment unique record number
**Date** is the date stamp when the record was created
**BatteryID** is the unique name for that battery, such a NiMh1, NiMh2 etc
**Capacity** is the measured capacity of that particular battery
**Type** is the type of battery such as NiMh AA, NiCD AAA, NiMh AAA, NiMh D etc

I want to...

1). Select All the batteries that are of type NiMh AA
2). From those I want to sort (Group) them by BatteryID
3). For each BatteryID,  I want to select ONLY the one with the latest date

This is the query string I'm using and it almost works, but does not pick the record for each battery with the latest DATE
I can't see how to tell the Group By clause to select the record withthe latest date in this situation.

Select BatteryID, capacity, Type, Notes from batteries where type='NiMh AA' group by BatteryID order by capacity

Thanks

**I get this.....**
Image 1

[image]

**I want this.....**

Image2

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very common reporting requirement.  In MySQL, you can handle this by joining to a subquery which does a `GROUP BY` to find the latest record for each battery group:

```
SELECT b1.*
FROM batteries b1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT BatteryID, MAX(Date) AS max_date
    FROM batteries
    WHERE type = 'NiMh AA'
    GROUP BY BatteryID
) b2
    ON b1.BatteryID = b2.BatteryID AND b1.Date = b2.max_date
WHERE
    b1.type = 'NiMh AA';
```

Comment: That gives me duplicates for some reason  But it looks very promising.   I'll try working with it.  Thanks.

Comment: What are you defining as a duplicate?  If a given battery have more than one record tied for the latest, what should happen?

Comment: Tim,  You are absolutely correct.  MY mistake was forgetting that the time was not part of the date so numerous records do in fact have the exact same max date.  Please accept my apologies and thank you for you time.  Brilliant solution.  best Regards.

Comment: How would I modify this Query so that instead of the one with the Latest Date being selected, it instead selected the record for each BatteryID with the greatest Capacity?  would I simply substitute Capacity where Date is specified in the original query?   I'll try it.

Comment: Tim, this has helped me so much.  Is there a way I can make some kind of a donation to your cause?